# How to verify an apple JWT using a public key

Tags: ios, jwt, apple-sign-in

I was following the instructions as mentioned [here](https://sarunw.com/posts/sign-in-with-apple-3/#what-to-validate) but I don't understand how to verify the token with the public key. This needs to be done before the what to validate step. I'm not even sure how I'd generate the public key. I understand hitting the apple get request for the JWKS but what do I do after that.

It would be great if someone could simplify this further.

Comment: Get Apple's keys from https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys. Use the `kid` claim to determine which key you need. Use the `e` and `n` values to create the public key. What language are you using on your server? Node.js?  There are modules that can help

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I'm using Node.js

Comment: @Zephyr you can use node-rsa. 
Does anyone know how to do this with crypto library

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: use Auth0 lib to check the token signature based on a token you will get from the JWT provider. Here is an example on how to do it based on Keycloak issued token, but with apple the only difference will be with maybe different cypher and public key retrieval method https://youtu.be/Dr4Ae61KGsM